# Grails 2.5.0 - Setting up JQGrid on fresh Grails install

Tags: grails, jqgrid

Steps I've done:

1. Create new project
2. Add `mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/core"` to the repositories in BuildConfig.groovy
3. Add `compile ":easygrid:1.7.1"` to the plugins in BuildConfig.groovy
4. Add the domain class com.test.Author with `String firstname` and `String lastname`
5. Add controller com.test.HomeController with `def index() { }`
6. Add file `views/home/index.gsp`

Next, I added the following to com.test.HomeController:

    `def authorJQGrid = {
        domainClass Author
        gridImpl 'jqgrid'
        jqgrid {
            sortname 'firstname'
        }
        export {
            export_title 'Author'
            pdf {
                'border.color' java.awt.Color.BLUE
            }
        }
        columns {
            firstname
            lastname
        }
    }`

And I added the following to home/index.gsp:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <asset:javascript src="easygrid.jqgrid.js"/>
    <asset:stylesheet src="easygrid.jqgrid.css"/>
</head>
<body>
            <grid:grid id='jqgridinitial' name='authorJQGrid'>
                <grid:set  width="900" caption="Authors"/>
            </grid:grid>
            <grid:exportButton name='authorJQGrid'/>
    </body>
</html>`

When I compile this, I see the following error:

`Could not process the EasygridConfig file`

When I try going to the webpage, I get the following error:

[http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request: [GET] /website/home/
Cannot get property 'authorJQGrid' on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Error processing GroovyPageView: Error executing tag : Cannot get property 'authorJQGrid' on null object

What can I do to get JQGrid working?

Comment: Did you annotate your Controller class with @Easygrid?

Comment: That was my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the plugin EasyGrid the controllers (where the Grids are defined) must be annotated with @Easygrid.

The example below, extracted from https://github.com/tudor-malene/grails-petclinic/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/org/grails/samples/OverviewController.groovy, show an example:

```
@Easygrid
class OverviewController {

    def ownersGrid = {
        domainClass Owner
        columns {
            id {
              type 'id'
              enableFilter false
            }
            firstName
            lastName
            address
            city
            telephone
            nrPets {
            enableFilter false
            value { owner ->
                owner.pets.size()
            }
            jqgrid {
                sortable false
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```